# Using an Arduino LDR Sensor to switch backgrounds in Processing

Tags: arduino, processing, arduino-uno

Using a LDR sensor for Arduino, I want to switch between two gif backgrounds in Processing depending on the intensity of light that the LDR senses. My Arduino set-up works and I can see a range of numbers in the Serial Monitor depending on the amount of light shined on the sensor - however I'm having trouble in Processing with making the switch between backgrounds. This is my first project combining Arduino with Processing so please forgive me if I've made any super obvious mistakes.

**Arduino Code**

```
    int sensorPin = A0; // select the input pin for LDR
int sensorValue = 0; // variable to store the value coming from the sensor

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600); //sets serial port for communication
}

void loop() {

  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin); // read the value from the sensor

  Serial.println(sensorValue); //prints the values coming from the sensor on the screen

  delay(100);

}
```

**Processing Code**

```
    //loads gif library for background

import gifAnimation.*;

Gif batmanGotham;

Gif batmanLair;

//loads Arduino 

import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;

int sensorValue = 0;


void setup() {

  size(1067, 800); //size of canvas

  batmanGotham = new Gif(this, "background.gif"); //set gif

  batmanGotham.play();

  batmanLair = new Gif(this, "batman_lab.gif");  //set second gif

  batmanLair.play();

  String portName = "/dev/cu.usbmodem14201";

  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);

  myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw() {

}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {

  if (sensorValue > 300) {

    image(batmanLair, 0, 0);   //lays down gif background

  } else {

    image(batmanGotham, 0, 0);   //lays down gif background
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcos is right, through you will be sending more than two bytes.
Let's assume you're sending `1023`, that is actually 4 characters (bytes) + another new line (from `println`).

You can draw continuously and simply update the image based on the data read, ideally with some error checking:

```
   //loads gif library for background

import gifAnimation.*;

Gif batmanGotham;

Gif batmanLair;

//loads Arduino 

import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;

int sensorValue = 0;


void setup() {

  size(1067, 800); //size of canvas

  batmanGotham = new Gif(this, "background.gif"); //set gif

  batmanGotham.play();

  batmanLair = new Gif(this, "batman_lab.gif");  //set second gif

  batmanLair.play();

  String portName = "/dev/cu.usbmodem14201";

  try{
    myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
    myPort.bufferUntil('\n');  
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error opening serial port: double check the cable is connected, the portName is right and SerialMonitor anything else trying to access the port is closed");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }


}

void draw() {
  if (sensorValue > 300) {

    image(batmanLair, 0, 0);   //lays down gif background

  } else {

    image(batmanGotham, 0, 0);   //lays down gif background
  }
}

void serialEvent (Serial myPort) {
  try{
    String rawString = myPort.readString();
    if(rawString != null && rawString.length() > 0){
      // remove newline
      rawString = rawString.trim();
      // parse value
      sensorValue = int(rawString);
    }
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error parsing serial data");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

If you want to keep the Processing Serial part simpler, you can do the threshold logic on arduino and simply send a single byte to Processing, like 1 or 0 depending on which image you want to display:

```
int sensorPin = A0; // select the input pin for LDR
int sensorValue = 0; // variable to store the value coming from the sensor

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600); //sets serial port for communication
}

void loop() {

  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin); // read the value from the sensor

  if(sensorValue > 0){
    Serial.print('1');
  }else{
    Serial.print('0');
  }

  delay(100);

}
```

Then in Processing:

```
   //loads gif library for background

import gifAnimation.*;

Gif batmanGotham;

Gif batmanLair;

//loads Arduino 

import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;

boolean showLair;


void setup() {

  size(1067, 800); //size of canvas

  batmanGotham = new Gif(this, "background.gif"); //set gif

  batmanGotham.play();

  batmanLair = new Gif(this, "batman_lab.gif");  //set second gif

  batmanLair.play();

  String portName = "/dev/cu.usbmodem14201";

  try{
    myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("error opening serial port: double check the cable is connected, the portName is right and SerialMonitor anything else trying to access the port is closed");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }


}

void draw() {
  // read 1 char
  if(myPort != null && myPort.available() > 0){
    char fromArduino = myPort.read();
    showLair = (fromArduino == '1');
  }
  // update content
  if (showLair) {

    image(batmanLair, 0, 0);   //lays down gif background

  } else {

    image(batmanGotham, 0, 0);   //lays down gif background
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Just FYI, in the second example for the Processing part, it didnt work until I changed the "char fromArduino = myPort.read();" line to an int, and then everything was great!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to read data from the serial port, try adding the following line on your `serialEvent()` routine:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
sensorValue   = myPort.readBytes(buffer);
```

at the very beginning.

As you see you have to recover data from the buffer yourself. The event is triggered automatically whenever there is something to read but you have to take is yourself from there and store it or process it.

You should be reading two bytes at a time to account for the size of the `int` you are sending from your Arduino.

Comment: I put that line right under the void Serial Event line but I got an error stating: Type mismatch, "byte[]" does not match with "int". I've looked at the Processing documentation and tried Googling but I'm not sure why that error is happening?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the argument for `readBytes` should be a byte array

Comment: No problem, thanks to your edit, the error disappear and the sketch actually will run .... except neither of my gifs actually pop up. I played around with the if(sensorValue) statement - if I put it in void draw(), the very last gif appears obviously. Do I need to declare the images in a different way?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with Processing. But I think calls to `image()` need to be within `draw()`